Polars - How to drop inf rows
I have a polars dataframe containing some rows with infinite values
(np.inf and -np.inf) which I'd like to drop.
I am aware ofdrop_nans and drop_null but I don't see a similar drop_inf. As I want to handle nan values separately, I cannot just replace inf with nan and then call drop_nans.
What's an idiomatic way of dropping rows with infinite values?

you can use DataFrame.filter() and Expr.is_infinite() to filter out rows you don't need:
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3, np.inf],
    "b": [1, 2, 3, 4]
})

df.filter(~pl.col('a').is_infinite())

┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 1   │
│ 2.0 ┆ 2   │
│ 3.0 ┆ 3   │
└─────┴─────┘

Or, if you want to check all columns for infinite values, you can use .any_horizontal():
import numpy as np
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3, np.inf],
    "b": [1, 2, -np.inf, 4]
})

df.filter(
    ~pl.any_horizontal(pl.all().is_infinite())
)

┌─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 │
│ 2.0 ┆ 2.0 │
└─────┴─────┘

If you have non-numeric columns you can also use selectors:
import numpy as np
import polars as pl
import polars.selectors as cs

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 2, 3, np.inf],
    "b": [1, 2, -np.inf, 4],
    "c": list("abcd")
})

df.filter(
    ~pl.any_horizontal(cs.numeric().is_infinite())
)

┌─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ f64 ┆ f64 ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 1.0 ┆ 1.0 ┆ a   │
│ 2.0 ┆ 2.0 ┆ b   │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘


Is there a way to apply the filtering without being explicit about any column name? I.e. filter out all the rows that have at least one inf value?

Thanks - I just tried that on a dataframe and am getting: polars.exceptions.InvalidOperationError: is_infinite operation not supported for dtype str
presumably because not all my columns are numerical. How do I make the filtering valid in that case, ignoring the columns for which is_infinite() is invalid?
